# Open PDFs from document Library without warning message in IE

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, document-library, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eliminating the “Some files can harm your computer” warning prompt](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/eliminating-the-some-files-can-harm-your-computer-warning-prompt)

I have enabled both Permissive Browser File Handling and added `AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add(“application/pdf”)` in PowerShell. I understand that doing both is a security risk.

Anyways, everytime the user clicks on a PDF item from the document Library, a popup window dispklays: ***Open Document: "Some files can harm your computer. If the file information below looks suspicious, or you do not fully trust the source, do not open the file."***

When I upload a PDF to an Announcement list item, the PDF opens directly without any message.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/1773/6382

Comment: I had added the icon, but not the opencontrol attribute. That seemed to do the trick. If you'd like to post as an answer so you get rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the accepted answer to the question [Eliminating the “Some files can harm your computer” warning prompt](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/1773/6382) where you can find which attribute you might be missing.

Good Luck!